# How to polar align equatorial mount if I see only small part of sky at south-east?

Tags: telescope, alignment, polaris

My mount is located on balcony where I can't see the polar star. I have only one window here which points to the eastern south. I limited by small piece of sky near the ecliptic plane between 120 degree and 140 by horizontal and 20 degree and 60 degree by vertical.

So, how can I align my mount in this case?

I tried to align it by aiming jupiter and saturn one by another and rotate the mount between. I get good enough result, but objects in frame is slowly move to out of frame (so, can't use long exposures).

Comment: With that little of the sky available, your results will likely be pretty limited.  Your best best is probably to try NINA/ASTAP alignment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJos0stpJvA

Comment: This should certainly be possible, and the ease will depend on details of your mount. Is it computer controlled or just a motor on one axis. How precisely can you read the RA and Dec from the mount? Are you reading from mechanical indicators or a digital readout?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://explorescientificusa.com/pages/polar-alignment-using-the-drift-method

Comment: @uhoh Computer controlled, not guided. Mechanical indicators

Comment: which mount do you have? can it be connected to a computer? if so then use kstars/ekos to do polar alignment: https://wthomaskelly.com/ekos-new-polar-alignment-routine-is-the-bees-knees (disclaimer: also requires camera connected to a computer)

Comment: @AaronF EQM-35 with SynScan EQDrive. Connected. But visible sky is limited

Comment: perfect - you'll be able to use the ekos polar alignment tool if you put an astrocamera in the eyepiece holder. a lot of the time i don't even bother polar aligning mine - i put it roughly in the right position and let the ekos plate solving routine get me pointing in the right place :-)

Comment: @Robotex, you have a computer controlled mount, but you have to rely on mechanical indicators?  The computer will display a digital readout of a EQM-35.  You should explain why the methods already mentioned won't work for you.

Comment: @AaronF you could write your answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you have sun hitting your balcony, you could draw a line of a shadow during solar noon.
You can put your place here and get the exact time: https://gml.noaa.gov/grad/solcalc/

I used a black water bottle, a ruler and a pencil to make a line on the floor.

Comment: It doesn't need to be solar noon, you can use the shadow at any time and just look up the azimuth of the Sun in a planetarium app, then use a protractor to find North.  But this will be very rough.  A "one start alignment" where you move the mount to center the star would be better, but this requires perfect elevation and level of the mount.